# Is there another way around to get proxy list and site scraping?

Tags: python, scrapy

By scraping I use Random proxy middleware for Scrapy  (https://github.com/aivarsk/scrapy-proxies).

At first, I get list.txt (list of proxies) by scraping free-proxy-site (without using proxy rotating) 
Then I make scraping of another site, (with proxy rotating)
When I run it by two different Scrapy projects it works well.

The question is how to combine getting proxy and scraping in one scrapy project or is there another way around to handle it?

I tried to run it together in one Scrapy project, unfortunately, it doesn't work. Probably because in this case scrapy-proxies tries to use list.txt for proxy rotating which is empty at that moment by request to free-proxy-site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option to implement scraping proxies and scraping website with proxies inside single spider class.
This [gist code sample](https://gist.github.com/GeorgeA92/b7c135f8135e13f542ca098f41d80fb5) implements this as [scrapy as script app](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script).

Comment: It really works! Thanks a lot. How about saving to database? It is possible to use Scrapy's item and pipeline to process extracted data or I should use an ORM to store to db?